# send_task works only with a specific user

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, amqp, celery-task, rabbitmqctl

**setup:** Celery 4.1,  RabbitMQ 3.6.1 (As broker), Redis (As backend, not relevant here).

Having two rabbit users:

- `admin_user` with permissions of `.* .* .*`.
- `remote_user` with permissions of `ack ack ack`.

`admin_user` can trigger tasks and is used by celery workers to handle tasks.

`remote_user` can only trigger one type of task - `ack` and is enqueued in a dedicated `ack` queue which later on being consumed by `ack` worker (by `admin_user`).

The `remote_user` sends the task by the following code:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('remote', broker='amqp://remote_user:remote_pass@<machine_ip>:5672/vhost')
app.send_task('ack', args=('a1', 'a2'), queue='ack', route_name='ack')
```

This works perfectly in Celery 3.1. After upgrade to Celery 4.1 it doesn't send the task anymore. The call returns an `AsyncResult` but I don't see the message in Celery flower (or via rabbit management ui), or in the logs.

- Trying to set permissions to `remote_user` `.* .* .*` as in the `admin_user` - doesn't help.
- Trying to add `administrator` tag - doesn't help.

Changing the user of the broker to 
`'amqp://admin_user:admin_pass@<machine_ip>:5672/vhost'` DOES work :

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('remote', broker='amqp://admin_user:admin_pass@<machine_ip>:5672/vhost')
app.send_task('ack', args=('a1', 'a2'), queue='ack', route_name='ack')
```

But I don't want to give a remote machine the `admin_user` permissions.
Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
API changed I guess, but to stay with the current permissions of RabbitMQ I had to use the following route:

**old_celery_config.py**: (celery 3.1)

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'ack_task': {
        'queue': 'geo_ack'
    }
}
```

**celery_config.py:** (celery 4.1)

```
CELERY_ROUTES = {
    'ack_task': {
        'exchange': 'ack',
        'exchange_type': 'direct',
        'routing_key': 'ack'
    }
}
```

**run_task.py:**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('remote', broker='amqp://remote_user:remote_pass@<machine_ip>:5672/vhost')
app.config_from_object('celery_config')
app.send_task('ack_task', args=('a1', 'a2'))
```